# Appending a character to a string throws Errors

Tags: c++, string

```
for(char c : charVec) {
    // // 1
    // string str;
    // str += c; //// ---- this is okay 

    // 2
    // string str = string(1, c); //// this is okay

    // 3
    string str = ""+ c; /// this is not okay and throws error

    ans.push_back(str);
}
```

Why does case 3 throw an error but case 1 does not?

I was expecting case 1 to be wrong and convert the character to a string by appending it with an empty string.

Comment: The type of `""` is not `std::string` that's the reason for the difference. C language has string literals, but not `std::string` so that is why `""` is not `std::string` in C++ too.

Comment: (3) converts the character array (`""` is one, it's not `std::string`) to a pointer, and the character to an integer, and then preforms pointer arithmetic on the two.

Comment: `string str = ""+ c; /// this is not okay and throws error` -- Do not use Java, JavaScript, or any other language as a model in writing C++ code.  If you continue to do this, you will end up with 1) Buggy code,  2) Inefficient code, and 3) code that looks weird to a C++ programmer.  Your attempt covers items 1) and 3).  A C++ programmer would never even think of writing code like this to try and concatenate strings.  Yes, this is a common way to do this in Java or Javascript, but it isn't the way to do this in C++, besides it looking totally odd.

Comment: Try `string str = ""s + c;`

Comment: Note: you need a `using namespace` statement for `""s` to work properly, either `using namespace std::literals`, or `using namespace std::string_literals`, or `using namespace std::literals::string_literals`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "add" a char to a string literal. (Well technically, you can, but it doesn't do what you think it does).

The string literal decays into a pointer to a character.  So `""+c` is nearly equivalent to this:

```
const char* s = "";  // s is equal to some address in memory
s += (int)c;   // s now points to some invalid address
```

The above does pointer arithmetic on the memory address that `s` is pointing at.  So if `c` is 'A', that means `s` now points to 65 bytes to the right of where that string literal lives in memory. That's undefined behavior.  Old-school "C" compilers would probably have allowed `""+c`, but modern compilers likely block this.

A string literal is not the same as a `std::string`.  Although, the latter can be constructed from one.

So, instead of this:

```
std::string str = ""+ c;
```

Use this:

```
std::string str(&c, 1);   // create a string of length 1 starting from the pointer specified by &c
```

Or:

```
std::string(1, c);      // create a string of 1 characters filled with c
```

Or:

```
std::string str = std::string("") + c;  // create an empty std::string and append c to it
// same as: std::string str = std::string() + c;
```

Or:

```
string str;
str += c;
```

Or:

```
// create a null terminated character array and use that as the string constructor
char tmp[2] = {c,'\0'};
string str(tmp);
```

There's other variations of the above.

Comment: Princess bride reference! But technically literal isn't a pointer but an array of  `length+1` chars. E.g. `s` there got type `char[1]`. The expression itself _can_ degrade to a  `const char*`